# Search database based on selection from 2 combobox - php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to come out with a simple search using the selected text from two comboboxes. I am struggling to get this right.
Here is my code:
any suggesting and help is greatly appreciated!

```
<form  method="POST" action="" >
<label for="From"> From : </label>
<select id="cmbfrom" name="from" onchange="document.getElementById('selected_text').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text" >
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="C">C</option>
 <option value="F">F</option>
 <option value="H">H</option>
 <option value="V">V</option>
</select>
<label for="To">  To: </label>
<select id="cmbto" name="to" onchange="document.getElementById('selected_text2').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text" >
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="F">F</option>
 <option value="V">V</option>
 <option value="H">H</option>
 <option value="C">C</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search">
</form>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {

$source = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['from']); //from value
echo $source;
}
$sql = mysql_query("select * from trips where tripfrom ='$source'");    

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo '<br/> ID: '.$row['id'];
echo '<br/> First Name: '.$row['firstname'];
echo '<br/> Last Name: '.$row['lastname'];
echo '<br/> Phone: '.$row['phonenum'];
echo '<br/> From: '.$row['tripfrom'];
echo '<br/> To: '.$row['tripdest'];
echo '<br/> Seats: '.$row['seats']; 
echo '<br/><br/>';
    }
```

?>

My intention is to search from the database using the combo boxes selection and for the results to appear on the same page as the combo boxes, maybe below them.

I am not sure how to do this. 
Getting an error:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: source

Filename: views/search.php

Line Number: 122

Please help . I am so new to php

Comment: do you have some kind of JS that puts the selected text into the input value arguments?

Comment: no not really, how do I do that

Comment: I was just re-reading your code. You do have a JS doing that. It's what you wrote inside "onchange". 
That code should work, can you explain what happens when you try it?

Comment: the records by default is already showing at the bottom of the page before I could do the search. Also when I tried to search by clicking the search button, nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

Okay.  From what you said in the comments you need to move the php code that should run after the search to a new file ('search-action.php'). Then on the `<form>` you should add and `action='search-action.php'` like this:

```
<form action='search-action.php'>
```

Then PHP will take care of everything when you press the submit button will take care of

Comment: how do i modify the code to be able to have the results in the same page? i definitely need it that was as the requirement is such

Comment: An old school approach would be copying the code on both files, the view and the action file. The modern approach would be to do it asynchronously using Javascript and JSON. Probably with JQuery. If you want I can point you to a tutorial for that.

Comment: yes please. I tried the old school way but the is an error that I don't know how to solve. I have added the edited code at my initial question on the top since I cannot do that in the comment area. Error is :A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: source

Filename: views/search.php

Line Number: 122